# Why do I get this error on stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Whenever I have Chrome's console open on stackoverflow and move the mouse over any page elements I see the following line in the console:

```
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
```

What's causing this? Is this some sort of heatmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not stackoverflow.com specfic message, it can come on other sites as well. Message is obvious that in browsers with Webkit engine such as Chrome, Safari those two properties are deprecated.

It seems that these errors come when ***jQuery*** is used on a page, jQuery tries to use these two properties.

***See this ticket on jQuery bugs where this issue was mentioned:***

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10531

Comment: i was looking at your site and your sticky notes demo on html5 is broken

Comment: @kobe: Though this is not a chat but FYI, it works: http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/html5sticky/

Comment: sorry to ask out of context , but somehow its stil not working for me , let me try on someother browser

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to [layers](http://www.irt.org/articles/js087/) which were introduced by Netscape long, long ago. Thankfully, they have been out of common use for about 10 years.

`layerX` and `layerY` refer to the [mouse position of an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.layerX) with regards to a layer.